# How to debug Haskell code?

Tags: debugging, haskell

I have a problem. I wrote a big Haskell program, and it always works with small input. Now, when I want to test it and generate a bigger input, I always get the message:

```
HsProg: Prelude.head: empty list
```

I use `Prelude.head` many times. What can I do to find out more or get a better error output to get the code line in which it happens?

Comment: what interpiter or compiler u use ?

Comment: Hope this will help you

[How to “debug” Haskell with printfs ?][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3546592/how-to-debug-haskell-with-printfs

Comment: See: [Tracking down errors in Haskell](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2139463/tracking-down-errors-in-haskell).

Comment: Test everything with quickcheck!

Comment: Not really an answer to your question, but you should probably consider refactoring your code. Using `head` that often sounds like a bad idea in the first place.

Comment: you should learn to use 'Debug.Trace (trace)'

Comment: howto use the safe version of head? (from the module safe)

Comment: Don't use `head`, it's bad.  As you just noticed.

Comment: How to use the safe version of `head` is probably worthy of a separate SO question. Though you may want to not use *either* version, and stick to pattern-matching instead.

Answer (score 85, accepted):

The GHCi option `-fbreak-on-exception` can be useful. Here's an example debugging session. First we load our file into GHCi.

```
$ ghci Broken.hs
GHCi, version 7.0.2: http://www.haskell.org/ghc/  :? for help
Loading package ghc-prim ... linking ... done.
Loading package integer-gmp ... linking ... done.
Loading package base ... linking ... done.
Loading package ffi-1.0 ... linking ... done.
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( Broken.hs, interpreted )
Ok, modules loaded: Main.
```

Now, we turn on `-fbreak-on-exceptions` and trace our expression (`main` in this case for the whole program).

```
*Main> :set -fbreak-on-exception
*Main> :trace main
Stopped at <exception thrown>
_exception :: e = _
```

We've stopped at an exception. Let's try to look at the code with `:list`.

```
[<exception thrown>] *Main> :list
Unable to list source for <exception thrown>
Try :back then :list
```

Because the exception happened in `Prelude.head`, we can't look at the source directly. But as GHCi informs us, we can go `:back` and try to list what happened before in the trace.

```
[<exception thrown>] *Main> :back
Logged breakpoint at Broken.hs:2:23-42
_result :: [Integer]
[-1: Broken.hs:2:23-42] *Main> :list
1  
2  main = print $ head $ filter odd [2, 4, 6]
3
```

In the terminal, the offending expression `filter odd [2, 4, 6]` is highlighted in bold font. So this is the expression that evaluated to the empty list in this case.

For more information on how to use the GHCi debugger, see [the GHC User's Guide](https://downloads.haskell.org/%7Eghc/8.10.3/docs/html/users_guide/ghci.html#debugging-exceptions).

Comment: Brilliant. I didn't seek information on the GHCi debugger, but this is really cool.

Comment: -fbreak-on-exception has changed to -fbreak-on-error.

Comment: @PetrGladkikh 404

Comment: https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/7.4.1/docs/html/users_guide/ghci-debugger.html

Answer (score 10):

You may want to take a look at [Haskell Wiki - Debugging](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Debugging), which contains many useful approaches to your problem.

One promising tool is [LocH](http://www.cse.unsw.edu.au/~dons/loch.html), which would would help you locate the `head` invocation in your code which triggered the *empty list* error.

Personally, I recommend the [safe](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/safe) package, which allows to annotate most *partial* functions from the Prelude (and thus leads to a more conscious use of those partial functions) or better yet, use the *total* variants of functions such as `head` which always return a result (if the input value was *defined* at least).

Comment: I'd first recommend not using `head` at all, especially for someone new to the language.

Comment: @camccann I fully agree... alas most introductory material I've seen (including the rather modern LYAH) starts out with explaining `head` and just warns about being careful not to apply it to empty lists... :-/

Comment: If I had *my* way I'd remove it (along with `tail`, `(!!)`, and some other stuff) from the `Prelude` entirely and never mention it to beginners at all. But oh well.

Comment: @hvr, ```loch``` fails to build in GHC 7. ```loch-th``` works for me, though. But seems it has no preprocessor support as ```loch``` had.

Comment: Your LocH link is giving me a 403 error, but I assume http://hackage.haskell.org/package/loch is the same tool?

Comment: @MatrixFrog, yes it is the same tool, but that page contains usage examples... seems they have changed the access config recently, but you can still access it [via archive.org](http://web.archive.org/web/20090616055853/http://www.cse.unsw.edu.au/~dons/loch.html)

Answer (score 3):

You can use this library: 
[Debug.Trace](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.0.0/docs/Debug-Trace.html)

You can replace any value a with the function:

`trace :: String -> a -> a`

unlike `putStrLn` there is no `IO` in the output, e.g.:

```
>>> let x = 123; f = show
>>> trace ("calling f with x = " ++ show x) (f x)
calling f with x = 123
123
```

The trace function should only be used for debugging, or for monitoring execution. The function is not referentially transparent: its type indicates that it is a pure function but it has the side effect of outputting the trace message.

Answer (score 2):

Since GHC 8, you can use the GHC.Stack module or some profiling compiler flags detailed [on a Simon's blog](https://simonmar.github.io/posts/2016-02-12-Stack-traces-in-GHCi.html).