# How to know which element not in Map when using Data.Map.!

Tags: haskell

I have a Haskell program which uses `Data.Map.!` at several places. After executing the program, there is error message saying `element not in the map`. 
I am wondering how can I know at which line of the program that uses the `Data.Map.!` that emits the error message and what element is not found in the map?

Comment: Don't use `(!)`. Use `lookup` instead.

Comment: Also, see here for a previous question about how to debug errors from unwisely using partial functions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6724434/howto-debug-a-haskell-code

Comment: Too bad that [safe](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/safe) does not have safe variants of `(!)`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `(!)` operator is not intended for looking up things that might not be in the map.  While you can catch the resulting error in the `IO` monad, it would be very bad style.

Instead, use `lookup`, which returns `Maybe a`, and in particular, returns `Nothing` when the element isn't in the map.

*Edit:* Okay, I misread your question.  Leaving the original answer in case it's useful, but supposing that `(!)` really was what you wanted and you're debugging, there are a couple things you could do:

1. You can temporarily hide `(!)` in the imports, and instead define your own version that uses `lookup` and throws a more useful error (perhaps containing the key that you tried to look up, if it has a Show instance).
2. You can run the code in the GHCi debugger, and use -fbreak-on-exception to stop the code where the lookup occurs.
3. You can use the `Debug.Trace` module to add trace statements to your code.