# Debugging loop in haskell

Tags: haskell

Say I had the following code in Haskell:

```
x :: Int
y :: Int
z :: Int
x=y
y=z
z=x
```

Naturally, referring to any of these variables causes execution to bomb with `<<loop>>` if using ghc or spin infinitely if using ghci. I'm working on some code that has high potential for circularity if miscoded - is there any way to debug `<<loop>>` - can I examine the stack when it bombs to see the circularity?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6724434/how-to-debug-haskell-code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I looked at [the question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6724434/how-to-debug-haskell-code) @TheInternet linked, and the first answer's advice to use <s>`-fbreak-on-exception`</s>`-fbreak-on-error` and `:trace` is pretty good. However I thought I'd mention two small snags I hit that are specific to this question:

1. GHCi does *not* make `<<loop>>` exceptions, only native compiled GHC does that, and the GHCi debugger cannot trace native compiled code.

Fortunately, this can be solved by pressing `^C` to interrupt manually.

2. Trying to `:trace` and then `^C` manually instead does give a debugger session, but GHCi hasn't inserted any breakpoints and so there's no context to debug!

This was also easy to fix: I just changed the first equation to `x = id y`. This is enough to get GHCi to insert breakpoints. I suspect that this problem was due to the OP's code cycle containing only trivial variable equations (to quote [the GHC User's Guide](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/ghci-debugger.html#setting-breakpoints): "*Single variables are typically not considered to be breakpoint locations (unless the variable is the right-hand-side of a function definition, lambda, or case alternative)*"), and that it will not usually happen in "real" code.