# How to use "trace" when dealing with an "out of memory" exception/stackoverflow in Haskell?

Tags: debugging, haskell, exception, stack-overflow, trace

Context: I'm writing an interpreter for a language which is basically a small subset of Haskell.

Haskell's lazy evaluation is being a poo and refusing to evaluate this `trace` command due to (I suspect) an infinite recursion which results in an "Out of memory" exception.

```
evalE :: VEnv -> Exp -> Value
evalE g e | trace ("VEnv: " ++ show g ++ "\nExp: " ++ show e ++ "\n\n") False = undefined
-- actual definition of evalE follows from here
-- ...
```

I'm getting the following result:

```
weber % ./run_tests.sh
Building minhs-0.1.0.0...
Preprocessing executable 'minhs-1' for minhs-0.1.0.0...
Check.hs: out of memory (requested 1048576 bytes)
weber %
```

Is there some easy way to force `trace` to evaluate, regardless of the exception? Perhaps a way to quickly force strict evaluation? I really would like to get some debugging info about what it's actually trying to evaluate.

edit: some further googling has revealed the ($!) operator, which is supposed to force strictness. However I've added it to my code and nothing has changed:

```
evalE g e | trace ("VEnv: " ++ show g ++ "\nExp: " ++ show e ++ "\n\n") $! False = undefined
```

Any other hints? I really want to force that trace to evaluate it's side effects.

edit2: yet more googling revealed the `seq` operator, however it is not behaving as advertised.

```
evalE g e | trace ("VEnv: " ++ show g ++ "\nExp: " ++ show e ++ "\n\n") False `seq` False = undefined
```

Even this refuses to print the trace.

I also worked out how to get the BangPatterns extension working, but that didn't print the trace either:

```
evalE !g !e | trace ("VEnv: " ++ show g ++ "\nExp: " ++ show e ++ "\n\n") False = undefined
```

(full file for reference. It's a multifile program though):

```
module MinHS.Evaluator where
import qualified MinHS.Env as E
import MinHS.Syntax
import MinHS.Pretty
import qualified Text.PrettyPrint.ANSI.Leijen as PP

import Debug.Trace

type VEnv = E.Env Value

data Value = I Integer
           | B Bool
           | Nil
           | Cons Integer Value
           | Fun VEnv [String] Exp
           deriving (Show)

instance PP.Pretty Value where
  pretty (I i) = numeric $ i
  pretty (B b) = datacon $ show b
  pretty (Nil) = datacon "Nil"
  pretty (Cons x v) = PP.parens (datacon "Cons" PP.<+> numeric x PP.<+> PP.pretty v)
  pretty _ = undefined -- should not ever be used

evaluate :: Program -> Value
evaluate [Bind _ _ _ e] = evalE E.empty e
evaluate bs = evalE E.empty (Let bs (Var "main"))

instance Num Value where
    I x + I y = I (x + y)
    I x * I y = I (x * y)
    I x - I y = I (x - y)
    abs (I x) = I (abs x)
    fromInteger x = I x

instance Integral Value where
    div _ (I 0) = error $ "Cannot divide by zero"
    div (I x) (I y) = I (div x y)
    mod (I x) (I y) = I (mod x y)

instance Real Value where

instance Enum Value where

instance Ord Value where
    I x > I y = x > y
    I x >= I y = x >= y
    I x <= I y = x <= y
    I x < I y = x < y

instance Eq Value where
    I x == I y = x == y
    I x /= I y = x /= y

evalE :: VEnv -> Exp -> Value
evalE g e | trace ("VEnv: " ++ show g ++ "\nExp: " ++ show e ++ "\n\n") False = undefined
evalE g (Num x) = I x
evalE g (App (Prim Neg) x) = (evalE g x) * (-1)
evalE g (Con "False") = B False
evalE g (Con "True") = B True
evalE g (Con "Nil") = Nil
evalE g (App (App (Prim Gt) x) y) = B ((evalE g x) > (evalE g y))
evalE g (App (App (Prim Ge) x) y) = B ((evalE g x) >= (evalE g y))
evalE g (App (App (Prim Lt) x) y) = B ((evalE g x) < (evalE g y))
evalE g (App (App (Prim Le) x) y) = B ((evalE g x) <= (evalE g y))
evalE g (App (App (Prim Eq) x) y) = B ((evalE g x) == (evalE g y))
evalE g (App (App (Prim Ne) x) y) = B ((evalE g x) /= (evalE g y))
evalE g (App (Prim Head) (Con "Nil")) = error $ "Cannot take head of empty list"
evalE g (App (Prim Tail) (Con "Nil")) = error $ "Cannot take tail of empty list"
evalE g (App (Prim Head) (App (App (Con "Cons") x) _)) = evalE g x
evalE g (App (Prim Tail) (App (App (Con "Cons") _) x)) = evalE g x
evalE g (App (Prim Null) list) = case evalE g list of
                                    Nil -> B True
                                    _ -> B False
evalE g (App (App (Con "Cons") (Num x)) y) = Cons x (evalE g y)
evalE g (App (App (Prim Add) x) y) = (evalE g x) + (evalE g y)
evalE g (App (App (Prim Mul) x) y) = (evalE g x) * (evalE g y)
evalE g (App (App (Prim Sub) x) y) = (evalE g x) - (evalE g y)
evalE g (App (App (Prim Quot) x) y) = div (evalE g x) (evalE g y)
evalE g (App (App (Prim Rem) x) y) = mod (evalE g x) (evalE g y)
evalE g (Let bindings exp) = evalE ((E.addAll g . (map (\(Bind str _ _ bexp) -> (str, evalE g bexp)))) bindings) exp
evalE g e@(Var x) = case E.lookup g x of
                    Just y -> y
                    Nothing -> error $ "Variable " ++ x ++ " not defined" ++ errz g e
evalE g (If exp t f) = case evalE g exp of
                        B True -> evalE g t
                        B False -> evalE g f
evalE g e@(Letfun (Bind name _ args exp)) = Fun (E.add g (name, evalE g e)) args exp
evalE g e@(App (Var x) exp) = case E.lookup g x of
                                Just (Fun env args f) -> evalE (E.addAll env [(head args, evalE g exp)]) f
                                Nothing -> error $ "Function " ++ x ++ " not defined" ++ errz g e
evalE g (App exp1 exp2) = case evalE g exp1 of
                            Fun env args f -> evalE (E.addAll env [(head args, evalE g exp2)]) f

evalE g e = error $ "No pattern" ++ errz g e
--evalE g e = error "Implement me!"

errz g e = "\nVEnv: \n" ++ show g ++ "\n\nExp: \n" ++ show e
```

Comment: I think you can add a run-time flag `-xc` I think - to get stack traces when programs crash - see https://neilmitchell.blogspot.co.at/2015/09/detecting-space-leaks.html for a great article about space leaks and how to find/fix them.

Comment: @epsilonhalbe that's cool, but I don't actually want a stack trace. I want to force evaluate the 'trace' expression so as to print the variable values to the screen in a formatted debug string

Comment: Also I don't really need to hunt down the memory leak because I already know exactly where it is. I really just want to print some values so I can see exactly what the program is working on

Comment: This would benefit from a [MCVE]. I'm pretty sure the problem is _not_ that “Haskell is refusing to evaluate the `trace`”, rather it probably _is_ evaluating the `trace` and that's triggering the problem (which lies in `g` or `e`, themselves, so you get the same error regardless of whether `trace` triggers it or the following function).

Comment: it is *not* evaluating the trace, because the side effect of "printing to stdout" is not happening. Instead the program just craps out with a stackoverflow exception. I want to see the intermediate values.

Comment: have you taken a look at the compiler output with `-ddump-simpl` maybe the optimizer (correctly IMHO) optimizes the guard with False away.

Comment: there is also a good idea to use ghci debugging see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6724434/how-to-debug-haskell-code) breaking on exceptions and [here](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/master/users-guide/ghci.html#ghci-debugger) for general info - it is definitely no big fun to use, but not to bad once you've used it a bit.

Comment: ps.: there is a lot of calling to `error` or `undefined` or partial functions (esp. 
 take a look at your instance declarations, they are problematic in my opinion), I'd advise you to use hlint and compiling with `-Wall`. Btw. you are using `errz` in a lot of expressions - which is essentially the same as your `trace` expression - If you have a recursive data-structure in `g` or `e` you would experience the same behaviour whether you have the trace expression or not - if you run into an error - for example in the `case lookup` part.

Answer (score 4):

I think what @leftroundabout is saying is that, if the evaluation of `g` or `e` triggers the problem, then the act of tracing will generate an exception before any output is traced.

`trace` marshals its argument out to a C string for output.  Therefore, `show g` and `show e` must be fully evaluated before `trace` prints a single character of output.

As an example, the following program:

```
import Debug.Trace

badsum = sum [1..1000000]

process g | trace ("processing " ++ show g) False = undefined
process _ = "whatever"

main = print (process badsum)
```

when compiled without optimizations and run with a small heap size:

```
$ stack ghc -- -fforce-recomp -rtsopts Trace
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( Trace.hs, Trace.o )
Linking Trace ...
$ ./Trace +RTS -M10M
Trace: Heap exhausted;
Trace: Current maximum heap size is 10485760 bytes (10 MB).
Trace: Use `+RTS -M<size>' to increase it.
```

generates an exception before the `trace` call prints anything.  In the process of evaluating `trace`, the value of `g` is fully evaluated, triggering an exception before `trace` generates output.

Replace the `trace` call with `trace "processing" False`, and the program prints the trace and runs to completion (since it never tries to evaluate `g`).

Comment: You can also reproduce this more simply, I suspect, by making `show g` demand an infinite amount of heap memory, so that you don't have to futz with runtime settings. For example, `let g = 1:g in trace ("exp: " ++ show g) $ head g`