# Detect what function is raising the exception Prelude.!!: negative index

Tags: haskell, haskell-prelude

I could not figure out in my code what function is raising `(*** Exception: Prelude.!!: negative index` since this exception is not very descriptive about the error. Is there any way to detect exactly what custom function is calling `!!` and raising this error.

This is a simple reproducible example of the error when is called `index_around 0 [1, 2, 3]`, here the exception text doesn't describe if the exception is raised by `index_before` or by `index_after` function.

```hs
index_before :: Int -> [a] -> a
index_before i list = list !! (i - 1)

index_after :: Int -> [a] -> a
index_after i list = list !! (i + 1)

index_around :: Int -> [a] -> (a, a)
index_around i list = (index_before i list, index_after i list)
```

Comment: GHCi has an inbuilt debugger that you can use. Look at [this StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6724525/17592995) for an example.

Comment: Thank you, I will check.

Answer (score 5):

There are a few methods you can use to debug haskell code:

- Using [`Debug.Trace`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.16.0.0/docs/Debug-Trace.html) which logs messages to `stderr` wherever you use the `trace` function. It requires modification of your code, and since `trace` is an impure function (which hides `IO` using `unsafePerformIO`), you should use it with caution.
- Using the [`-xc`](https://downloads.haskell.org/%7Eghc/8.10.3/docs/html/users_guide/runtime_control.html#rts-flag--xc) [`RTS`](https://downloads.haskell.org/%7Eghc/9.0.1/docs/html/users_guide/runtime_control.html#running-a-compiled-program) flag after compiling with `-prof -fprof-auto`,  which gives you the exact call stack when an exception is raised.
- Using the [`GHCi` debugger](https://downloads.haskell.org/%7Eghc/8.10.3/docs/html/users_guide/ghci.html#debugging-exceptions). A good example of how to use it can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6724525/17592995).

Comment: Thank you I will look into them

Answer (score 1):

When you call `index_around 0 [1, 2, 3]`, you're calling `index_before (-1) [1, 2, 3]` and `index_after 1 [1, 2, 3]`.

`-1` is a negative index.

You may wish to do some bounds checking, and employ the `Maybe` type. This way the exception never happens.

```
index_around :: Int -> [a] -> (Maybe a, Maybe a)
index_around n lst 
    | length lst == 0 = (Nothing, Nothing)
    | n == 0          = (Nothing, Just $ index_after n lst)
    | n == length lst = (Just $ index_before n lst, Nothing)
    | otherwise       = (Just ib, Just ia) 
          where ib = index_before n lst
                ia = index_after n lst
```

Comment: Yes, in the example is obvious, but when you have a main entry point and a lot of functions that calls `!!` is hard to detect which of your functions is raising the error. The objective of the question is to get programmatically exactly what function raises the exception, since the exception description is not very informative. Get a traceback will be great.